# Model file not overriden in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, model, override-model

I am trying to override Model file in my custom module like below.

**Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

<preference for="Magento\InventorySales\Model\IsProductSalableCondition\BackOrderNotifyCustomerCondition" type="Vendor\Module\Model\IsProductSalableCondition\BackOrderNotifyCustomerCondition" />

</config>
```

Then **Vendor\Module\Model\IsProductSalableCondition\BackOrderNotifyCustomerCondition**

```
<?php 

  declare(strict_types=1);

 namespace Vendor\Module\Model\IsProductSalableCondition;

 use Magento\InventoryConfigurationApi\Api\Data\StockItemConfigurationInterface;
use Magento\InventoryConfigurationApi\Api\GetStockItemConfigurationInterface;
use Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\Data\ProductSalabilityErrorInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\Data\ProductSalableResultInterface;
use Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\Data\ProductSalableResultInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyInterface;
use Magento\InventorySalesApi\Model\GetStockItemDataInterface;

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */

class BackOrderNotifyCustomerCondition implements 
 IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyInterface
{
/**
 * @var GetStockItemConfigurationInterface
 */
private $getStockItemConfiguration;

/**
 * @var GetStockItemDataInterface
 */
private $getStockItemData;

/**
 * @var ProductSalableResultInterfaceFactory
 */
private $productSalableResultFactory;

/**
 * @var ProductSalabilityErrorInterfaceFactory
 */
private $productSalabilityErrorFactory;

/**
 * @param GetStockItemConfigurationInterface $getStockItemConfiguration
 * @param GetStockItemDataInterface $getStockItemData
 * @param ProductSalableResultInterfaceFactory $productSalableResultFactory
 * @param ProductSalabilityErrorInterfaceFactory $productSalabilityErrorFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    GetStockItemConfigurationInterface $getStockItemConfiguration,
    GetStockItemDataInterface $getStockItemData,
    ProductSalableResultInterfaceFactory $productSalableResultFactory,
    ProductSalabilityErrorInterfaceFactory $productSalabilityErrorFactory
) {
    $this->getStockItemConfiguration = $getStockItemConfiguration;
    $this->getStockItemData = $getStockItemData;
    $this->productSalableResultFactory = $productSalableResultFactory;
    $this->productSalabilityErrorFactory = $productSalabilityErrorFactory;
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function execute(string $sku, int $stockId, float $requestedQty): ProductSalableResultInterface
{
    $stockItemConfiguration = $this->getStockItemConfiguration->execute($sku, $stockId);

    if ($stockItemConfiguration->getBackorders() === StockItemConfigurationInterface::BACKORDERS_YES_NOTIFY) {
        $stockItemData = $this->getStockItemData->execute($sku, $stockId);
        if (null === $stockItemData) {
            return $this->productSalableResultFactory->create(['errors' => []]);
        }

        $backOrderQty = $requestedQty - $stockItemData[GetStockItemDataInterface::QUANTITY];
        if ($backOrderQty > 0) {
            $errors = [
                $this->productSalabilityErrorFactory->create([
                        'code' => 'back_order-not-enough',
                        'message' => __(
                            'We don\'t have as many quantity as you requested, '
                            . 'but we\'ll back order the remaining %1.',
                            $backOrderQty * 1
                        )])
            ];
            return $this->productSalableResultFactory->create(['errors' => $errors]);
        }
    }

    return $this->productSalableResultFactory->create(['errors' => []]);
  }
}
```

Which is not overriding to my custom module, can anyone tell where exactly the issue is? Suggest me if any other possibilities using plugin or something.

Thanks

Comment: Which function do you want to override in your custom module?

Comment: i want to override checkQuoteItemQty  function.

Comment: @Sumit, updated my question, was trying different class, pls check now

Comment: Magento Version??

Comment: 2.3.2 is magento version

Comment: Magento\InventorySales\Model\IsProductSalableCondition i cant see this file in magento 2.3.2

Comment: please check your function file or path which you want to override

Comment: @RkRathod, pls check my question, I have updated it, missed something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99031/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-rk-rathod).

Comment: Please use the plugin as you want to override

Answer (score 0):

What i have observed You can not override this file because this functions contains private variables and **you can not override private variables and methods.**

**So basically now you have a option to override with plugin.** [Click here](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-use-plugin-preference-rewrite-block-model-controller-helper-magento-2.html) for how to override method **through plugin in Magento2**.

Please use **after plugin.** so that you can override this method.

Code Spinnet:

> Path: app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="Magento\InventorySales\Model\IsProductSalableCondition\BackOrderNotifyCustomerCondition" type="Vendor\Module\Model\IsProductSalableCondition\BackOrderNotifyCustomerCondition" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>    
</config>
```

> Path: Vendor\Module\Model\IsProductSalableCondition\BackOrderNotifyCustomerCondition.php

```
<?php 

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\IsProductSalableCondition;

public function afterBackOrderNotifyCustomerCondition(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result){

    //return $result;   #This Variable will return at end.
}
```

Comment: hi, if you can pls update me the plugin code for my file which i'm trying to override. Thanks

Comment: Updated code, Please check!!

Comment: is it working? not in my case

Comment: This is an Sample, now you need to manuplate your values or put your desired code. between afterBackOrderNotifyCustomerCondition Method

Comment: You need to Change Module Name, Vendor Name, Also Put Logic in Method.

Comment: What logic need to apply here, to change the message text "We don\'t have as many quantity as you requested", can u update that pls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99035/discussion-between-oscprofessionals-and-jafar-pinjar).

Comment: Not working, have u tried the code?

Comment: Yes, I have already tried this, can you show me screen, where exactly the problem please.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided you have two `namespace` declared.

[image]

Remove one of them and test

Comment: no its a mistake while raising question, only once it is there in my file